# How can I calculate $\frac {\sqrt e}2-1$ without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Specifically:  I want to prove that $$\frac {\sqrt {e}}2-1<0$$ The only way I can think of is:

$e<4 \implies  \sqrt e<2$  (by squaring both sides) $\implies  \frac {\sqrt e}2<1\implies  \frac {\sqrt e}2-1 < 0$

Is there another way? Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: What's wrong with that method?  It looks optimal (well, assuming you know that $e<4$ that is).

Comment: Why do you need another way? That way is fine.

Comment: If you need another way, note that multiplying both sides by $\left(\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2} + 1\right)$ gives $\frac{e}{4}-1<0$

Comment: What is your definition of $e$? There are several equivalent definitions, but to prove that $e<4$, we need to know which one you are starting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative

$$\frac {\sqrt {e}}2-1<0\iff \frac {\sqrt {e}}2<1 \iff \sqrt {e}<2 \iff e<4$$

which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by conjugate $\frac{\sqrt e}{2}+1$:
$$\frac {\sqrt {e}}2-1<0 \Rightarrow \frac {e}4-1<0 \Rightarrow e<4.$$

Comment: Very smart answer!

Comment: Thanks, offerred as an alternative!

Answer (score 0):

A good approximate value for the expression is $-0.17563936465$.

As the comments suggest, your approach works. Another option is to use approximate value for the function:

One of the approximation methods is Taylor Series, around zero, if perform the expansion you get many terms like this:

$$\sqrt{e^{x}}\approx P\left(x\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{8}x^{2}+\frac{1}{48}x^{3}+\frac{1}{384}x^{4}+\frac{1}{3840}x^{5}$$

However, you may only be interested in the first 3 (since you don't want to use a calculator).

So, $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}-1 \approx  (0.5+0.25x+0.0625x)-1$$

When x=1, we get:

$$f(1) \approx -0.1875  < 0$$ as you wanted to show.